# How to use Python 3 to pick one or more items from a list

Tags: python, list

I am learning Python 3 and am trying to answer the below question, which asks to fill in a line of code toward the end. I put in the line in bold but need help to understand what I am doing wrong. I read similar questions posted on StackOverflow but all seem more advanced than what I am trying to do. Thank you.

Please fill in the blank so that the following code successfully iterates through the data stored in "makeup_products" and extracts the total number of shades for items that are meant just for "Lips", storing the total in a variable called `total_count_lip_shades`.

```
makeup_products = {"Products": [
                    {"Primer": {
                               "Shades": 15, 
                               "Styles": 5,
                               "Location": "Face"
                            }
                    },
                    {"Lipstick": {
                               "Shades": 48, 
                               "Styles": 3,
                                "Location": "Lips"
                              }
                    },
                    {"Lip liner": {
                               "Shades": 32, 
                               "Styles": 4,
                                "Location": "Lips"
                               }
                    },
                    {"Blush": {
                            "Shades": 13, 
                            "Styles": 2,
                            "Location": "Face"
                          }
                    },
                    {"Eye Liner": {
                               "Shades": 14, 
                               "Styles": 7,
                               "Location": "Eye"
                               }
                    },
                    {"Travel Makeup Kit": {
                               "Shades": "N/A",
                               "Styles": 3,
                               "Location": "Face, Lips, Eye"
                               }
                    }
                 ] }


total_count_lip_shades = 0
for item in makeup_products["Products"]:
    for product in item:
       **IF ITEM[PRODUCT]["LIP STICK", "LIP LINER"]**
            shade_count = item[product]["Shades"]
            total_count_lip_shades += shade_count
```

Comment: With Python 3 questions, use the [python-3.x] tag please.

Comment: I suggest you specify what the results you are looking for should look like. For example, the value of each variable after running your loop. That would help whoever tries to reproduce the results.

Answer (score 0):

You just need an `if` statement that checks if the `Location` value is equal to `Lips`:

```py
makeup_products = {"Products": [
                    {"Primer": {
                               "Shades": 15, 
                               "Styles": 5,
                               "Location": "Face"
                            }
                    },
                    {"Lipstick": {
                               "Shades": 48, 
                               "Styles": 3,
                                "Location": "Lips"
                              }
                    },
                    {"Lip liner": {
                               "Shades": 32, 
                               "Styles": 4,
                                "Location": "Lips"
                               }
                    },
                    {"Blush": {
                            "Shades": 13, 
                            "Styles": 2,
                            "Location": "Face"
                          }
                    },
                    {"Eye Liner": {
                               "Shades": 14, 
                               "Styles": 7,
                               "Location": "Eye"
                               }
                    },
                    {"Travel Makeup Kit": {
                               "Shades": "N/A",
                               "Styles": 3,
                               "Location": "Face, Lips, Eye"
                               }
                    }
                 ] }


total_count_lip_shades = 0
for item in makeup_products["Products"]:
    for product in item:
       if item[product]["Location"] == "Lips":
            shade_count = item[product]["Shades"]
            total_count_lip_shades += shade_count
```